# SharePoint List New form passed with Params from PowerApps

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-form, powerapp, powerapps-forms

I have SharePoint list form which is passed with URL params (PIID and CCID) which consists of Primary keys (Unique Identifiers) from two other SharePoint lists that are related, this causes the SharePoint List form to extract values from the two lists and populate the related fields.

My confusion is, where is the mapping of the fields occurring? For example how does the SharePoint list form know to populate the name field on the form with the name field from ListA?

Some of the fields have the exact same column names but others don't?

Example of List:

- List A (Contains User information)
- List B (Contains Car information)
- List form C (Contains insurance claim information)

Example of the URL:

```
https://SharePointSite/Lists/Intake/NewForm.aspx?PIID=399&CCID=420
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to know is that you **cannot** directly pass parameters to the NewForm.aspx, EditForm.aspx and ViewForm.aspx forms inside SharePoint. The only way to do this is by using the URL of the Power App.

You can get the App ID from app details page & construct the app URL with parameters.

Secondly, even if you pass the parameters in form URL, it cannot pre-populate the fields on forms automatically. You have to read those parameters, fetch the details from another lists based on this parameters and pre-populate the fields with these details.

Check this article for more information on how you can pass parameters to your Power Apps SharePoint form: [Passing parameters to your Power Apps SharePoint form](https://www.about365.nl/2020/08/06/passing-parameters-to-your-power-apps-sharepoint-form/)

Also, check this documentation related to "Param" function: [Param function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-param)

Answer (score 0):

How do you make param work with SharePoint list form?(Per my test this only works on canvas app)

Normally, When we specify Parmater with function Param("ParamName"), then append the parameter name and value to power apps canvas url, it will show the related value in app:

[image]

[image]

More information for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-param